# IIS 8 redirect loop when loading https

Tags: iis, https, iis-8, redirect-loop

I have 2 Windows 2012r2 Servers (Dev and Production) both running IIS 8. Both were configured identically as far I as know. I am in the process of installing wildcard certs on both of them.

I installed the cert on my Dev server and it's working. One thing that surprised me though was that I didn't have to add any additional bindings to any of my site configs (eg: I didn't add https/443) and just simply changing http to https in the browser is working, and showing the cert. Why is that?

My main question though is that on my Production server, before importing the wildcard cert, I tried simply changing the url for a couple of the domains I host from http to https in a browser to see what the result would be. When I do this I'm getting a redirect loop for all https tests. ???

I don't have any https URL Rewrites configured so I don't know what the cause of the redirect loop is. It does it for all sites on this server when trying to load it using https.

example:

http://mydomain.example.com (works)

https://mydomain.example.com (redirect loop)

Safari says, "...redirected you too many times. ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS"

Chrome says, "Too many redirects occurred..."

Additionally, if I load http://localhost on the server itself it works. If I load https://localhost I get an error, "Not Found - HTTP Error 404".

I should add that this Production server is behind an F5 Load Balancer so that could be playing into this behavior as well.

Answer (score 1):

The cause of the redirect loop for all sites on the Production server was an irule on the F5 LB, that shouldn't have been there, that was looping port 443 back to itself.  HTTPS for all sites worked after the irule was removed.

With regards to the Dev server and https sites working without having to add a binding. I also discovered that the F5 was configured to handle certs with a wildcard cert so local certs weren't even required. The data center team didn't communicate to me that the LB was configured to handle certs for these servers.